# What is not having a dominant foot called?

Tags: single-word-requests

If not having a certain dominant hand (or "both-handed") is called being ambidextrous, what is it called if you are "both-footed"?

Comment: Most people aren't even aware that they have a dominant foot, so there's not likely to be much in the way of (non-medical) terminology for it.

Comment: Duh? Ambipedantic!

Comment: @bib I was thinking something similar... ambipedrous?

Comment: If you can't dance (or are very clumsy) we say, "You have two left feet."  How about: "He has two right feet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Ambidextrous' is the word.

'ambi-' = both, '-dextrous' = right, so together it is as though both are equally dominant. Usually, your feet (and eyes) follow the same dominance as your hands. So if your hands are both dominant, your feet will both be dominant, too.

But if for some reason your feet have different dominance pattern than your hands, maybe you're left handed but right-footed, then you'd say well right-*footed*. And if both feet are dominant, then the way to say it is

> your feet are ambidextrous.

Comment: It is far from uncommon for people to be right-handed and left-footed.

Answer (score 4):

***Two-footed*** is used in sports, especially in soccer/football.

> Of a footballer: able to kick equally well with either foot. *[OED]*

***[Ambipedal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two-footed)*** is a synonym but it is not a common word like *ambidextrous*.